# Manually invoke RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: mvvm

Is it MVVM correct to manually invoke RaisePropertyChanged on some property, for example that has no setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most definitely.

Here is an example: Assume a Person class has 3 properties: firstName, lastName and fullName. fullName is a read only property (only a getter). Then the setter of firstName will raise property changed for both the "firstName" property as well as the "fullName" property.

Answer (score 0):

Then the value of the property is never changed? Why no setter? 
Anyway you can do that yes.